# Process denormalized JSON with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have the following JSON file which I want to process using python (this is, to obtain data from certain fields and do some calculations and analysis with it).

JSON file:

```
{
    "object1":{
       "field1.1":"value1",
       "field1.2":"value2",
       "field1.3":"value3",
       "field1.4":"value4",
       "field1.5":"value5",
       "field1.6":"value6",
       "field1.7":"",
       "field1.8":"",
       "field1.9":"",
       "field1.10":""
    },
    "object2":[
       {
          "field2.1":0,
          "field2.2":"value2",
          "field2.3":"value3",
          "field2.4":"20"
       }
    ],
    "object3":{
       "field3.1":0,
       "field3.2":0,
       "field3.3":"value5"
    },
    "object4":[
       {
          "field4.1.1":"value1",
          "field4.1.2":"10",
          "field4.1.3":128,
          "field4.1.4":0
       },
       {
          "field4.1.1":"value1",
          "field4.1.2":"1400",
          "field4.1.3":"value5",
          "field4.1.4":1
       }
    ],
    "object5":[
       {
          "field5.1":0,
          "field5.2":"value1",
          "field5.3":"value7",
          "field5.4":"6"
       }
    ]
 }
```

How can I read this JSON file using python Pandas?
I tried to do pd.read_json(json_path) but I always obtain an error, no matter what type of JSON orientation (split, index, etc.) I use.

Comment: Will you please add a sample dataframe that you want to be able to get?

Comment: I would like to end up with something like:
value1 (for field 1.1) | value 2 (for field 1.2) | value of field4.1.2 * value of field4.1.3 (which results in 1280)

Comment: Will you please just show a sample dataframe? I find it difficult to understand what you're trying to do. It'll help me a time and save time :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that will unnest all nested field in your data:

```
def flatten_nested_json_df(df):
    df = df.reset_index()
    s = (df.applymap(type) == list).all()
    list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    
    s = (df.applymap(type) == dict).all()
    dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

    
    while len(list_columns) > 0 or len(dict_columns) > 0:
        new_columns = []

        for col in dict_columns:
            horiz_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df[col]).add_prefix(f'{col}.')
            horiz_exploded.index = df.index
            df = pd.concat([df, horiz_exploded], axis=1).drop(columns=[col])
            new_columns.extend(horiz_exploded.columns) # inplace

        for col in list_columns:
            #print(f"exploding: {col}")
            df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].explode().to_frame())
            new_columns.append(col)

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == list).all()
        list_columns = s[s].index.tolist()

        s = (df[new_columns].applymap(type) == dict).all()
        dict_columns = s[s].index.tolist()
    return df
```

and then do this:

```
results = pd.json_normalize(data) #data is your json 
df = pd.DataFrame(results)

outdf = flatten_nested_json_df(df)
```

which results in

```
index object1.field1.1 object1.field1.2 object1.field1.3 object1.field1.4  \
0      0           value1           value2           value3           value4   
0      0           value1           value2           value3           value4   
0      0           value1           value2           value3           value4   
0      0           value1           value2           value3           value4   

  object1.field1.5 object1.field1.6 object1.field1.7 object1.field1.8  \
0           value5           value6                                     
0           value5           value6                                     
0           value5           value6                                     
0           value5           value6                                     

  object1.field1.9  ... object2.field2.3  object2.field2.4  \
0                   ...           value3                20   
0                   ...           value3                20   
0                   ...           value3                20   
0                   ...           value3                20   

   object4.field4.1.1 object4.field4.1.2  object4.field4.1.3  \
0              value1                 10                 128   
0              value1                 10                 128   
0              value1               1400              value5   
0              value1               1400              value5   

  object4.field4.1.4 object5.field5.1 object5.field5.2 object5.field5.3  \
0                  0                0           value1           value7   
0                  0                0           value1           value7   
0                  1                0           value1           value7   
0                  1                0           value1           value7   

  object5.field5.4  
0                6  
0                6  
0                6  
0                6  

[4 rows x 26 columns]
```